# как добавить новые UI элементы в ViewController где нет места?

Tags: xcode, swift3, storyboard

Добрый день/вечер!

Как добавить новые элементы в view controller, если уже нету места в самом контроллере?

[image: viewcontroller]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы элементы во ViewController можно было скроллить, вам нужно использовать UIScrollView. Информацию по поводу использования UIScrollView можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhhW3xqhCzg) в формате видео туториала или [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/222725/)

Comment: извините подравил вопрос, но суть понял. т.е. чтобы поместить все элементы мне нужно использовать free form растянуть контроллер, перетащить scroll view и в него закинуть все элементы ?

Comment: @MixmaxMakster, да, все верно. В туториалах по шагам показано как это сделать